# Manage unique encryption key in module for every installation

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on Payment Gateway. for data encryption and decryption I want to write encryption key for particular extension at the time of installation.

My question is which is the better way to manage key specific to particular extension ?

can I write key in module config.xml file ?   Or Can i write one new file in module to generate key ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

During installation you can generate key and store it in database in `core_config_data`.

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('path/to/config_value', $value, $scope, $scopeId);
```

Also you can make this config field editable in `System->Configuration`. So customer can change encryption key.

In addition in configuration you can add regenerate button, to allow admin to regenerate encryption key.